# Checking inputs in c# using regex to prevent injections

Tags: c#, regex, validation, input

I'm trying to check if a string has any kind of injection.
The problem is that i am new c#, so i don't know if im doing it right.

The text could be one of the next things:

- usernames (numbers and alphabet in english/hebrew).
- names.
- addresses
- descriptions(plain text with basic haracters like dots comas etc)

heres what i've done so far:
https://www.regex101.com/r/tQ0iK1/2

What I'm trying to do is simply to protect my inputs against injections.
So if there is another way, ill do it.

And if it is not necessary to protect inputs using c# then forgive me, i come from the world of web development.

Thanks ahead :)

Comment: Injections where? I thing it is good to validate the user input but if You do for security reason - you afraid the string will crash the app - Is not nessesery

Comment: The question sounds too broad, regex cannot detect a name or an address, please reconsider your requirements.

Comment: what if my username is `';drop tables` and similar

Comment: What types of injection do you want to guard against? For example you should escape ' (or block it) if you are worried about SQL injections

Comment: yup SQL, and mostly, and i preffer to escape instead of blocking.

Comment: @SamuelElgozi: Come up with a list of allowed and restricted characters first. Some people have already suggested `'` and `;`, `--` might harm SQL query too.

Answer (score 0):

> And if it is not necessary to protect inputs using c# then forgive me,
>   i come from the world of web development.

Instead of trying to use a regex to do this you can leverage built in IIS functionality.

You can use a [`security`](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security) config block in `System.webServer` to take care of most of it:

E.g. this would block `script>` and `script&lt;`

```
<system.webServer>
   <!-- other blocks -->
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <denyQueryStringSequences>
            <add sequence="script&lt;" />
            <add sequence="script>" />
          </denyQueryStringSequences>
          <verbs />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
   <!-- other blocks -->
</system.webServer>
```

More on [denyquerystring](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/denyquerystringsequences). This way your security is for the entire website, and you don't have to roll code for everything and you can keep code validation to match business rules.

Comment: The program I'm working on right now is a local program. I meant that i started programing on the web. And i thought that  maybe in c# there is no need in checking the inputs(yea i know it sound ridiculous)...